# Which trigger fires first

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have two different triggers on my table to insert records on another table. Can anybody explain which one fires first?

And why?

Answer (score 1):

If you have several triggers for the same condition, you can use `sp_settriggerorder` to specify the first and the last of them to execute. Everything in between is undetermined:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186762.aspx

Answer (score 0):

all of the BEFORE triggers will fire *in some order* (the documentation goes as far to 
say "you cannot control the order")

then, all of the BEFORE FOR EACH ROW will fire *in some order*

then, all of the AFTER for each row *in some order*

then all of the AFTER triggers *in some order*

If your triggers depend on the "firing order", you NEED to (must) consolidate them into a 
single trigger (put them in separate procedures, have one trigger that calls them in 
order)

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to guarantee which trigger will fire first. If your code is dependent on the order of execution then put all the code in the same trigger.